# Consume SalesForce over OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am using DotNetOpenAuth libraries to implement OAuth 2.0 client side to communicate with SalesForce authorization server. I have finished first two steps of OAuth 2.0 communication that ends with obtaining of access token from SalesForce authorization server.

Now I want to get some resource form SF. Is that possible only over REST service infrastructure ? Can I can send http request with access token and specified parameter to be retrieved to SF ?

Thank you,
Rastko

Comment: By the way, there is an extra Salesforce forum on the Stackexchange: salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ooo I did not know that, tnx a lot !